# Compare lines in a file

Tags: perl, hash, dataset, large-files

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
identifier,feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, ...
29239999, 2,5,3,...
29239999, 2,4,3,...
29239999, 2,6,7,...
17221882, 2,6,7,...
17221882, 1,1,7,...
```

I would like to write a script that groups these lines by identifier (so the first 3 and the last 2 would be grouped) in order to compare them. So, for example, I would get the 3 29239999 and take one of the two with feature 3 as 3 and the last with feature 3 as 7. In particular, I would like to take the one that has the largest feature 2 (it would be the third line for 29239999).

My specific question: of my two options: (1) hashes and (2) making each identifier an object and then comparing them, which is the best?

Comment: Hashes. But how exactly do you intend to compare, or does that not matter?

Comment: Hashes of course, however if the data is already grouped by identifier, you may not need anything more than a simple array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are working with a "large" data set and the data is already grouped by id like in your example, then I suggest that you process these as you go instead of building a huge hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Skip Header row
<DATA>;

my @group;
my $lastid = '';

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($id, $data) = split /,\s*/, $_, 2;

    if ($id ne $lastid) {
        processData($lastid, @group);
        @group = ();
    }

    push @group, $data;
    $lastid = $id;
}

processData($lastid, @group);

sub processData {
    my $id = shift;

    return if ! @_;

    print "$id " . scalar(@_) . "\n";

    # Rest of code here
}

__DATA__
identifier,feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, ...
29239999, 2,5,3,...
29239999, 2,4,3,...
29239999, 2,6,7,...
17221882, 2,6,7,...
17221882, 1,1,7,...
```

Outputs

```
29239999 3
17221882 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to print only the first occurrence of any pair of ID and Feature 3. Is that right?

This program will do that for you. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and send the revised data to STDOUT.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

print scalar <>; # Copy header line

while (<>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  my @fields = split /,/, $_, 5;
  my $key = join '/', @fields[0,3];
  print unless $seen{$key}++;
}
```

**output**

```
identifier,feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, ...
29239999, 2,5,3,...
29239999, 2,6,7,...
17221882, 2,6,7,...
```

Comment: Actually, I want to print one of the unique occurrences of any pair of ID and feature 3. It may be the first, it may be 2nd, 3rd, etc.. Let's say, whichever one has a larger feature 2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I can see that your code works, but I don't fully understand it, so I couldn't use it.

Comment: @user2795733: It works by creating a hash key from the ID and Feature 3 - for instance `"29239999/3"` - and printing a line if that key has never been seen before. So it prints the first in the set. You sound a little vague about which member of each set you want to print. If you want anything other than the first then you would have to do something more complicated that can compare all the lines in a set before choosing one to print. If you have a *"large dataset"* then it may be impossible to read all of the data into memory at once.